# Limit the bottom bar to the text and not the window width

Tags: css

I've this style for my titles on my website:

```css
.heading-text>* {
  position: relative;
}

.heading-text h4 {
    font-size: 34px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    letter-spacing: -.7px;
    line-height: 40px;
}

.heading-text.heading-line h4:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 15px;
    bottom: 5px;
    background-color: #fcf8e3;
    z-index: -1
}
```

```html
<div class="heading-text heading-line">
  <h4>
    My super loooong title
  </h4>
</div>

<div class="heading-text heading-line">
  <h4>
    My short title
  </h4>
</div>
```

The issue I'm facing is the yellow bar is not fitting the text width.

Is there a way it can be adjust automatically ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make the `h4` not take the whole screen, by using `display:inline-block;`

```css
.heading-text>* {
  position: relative;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: The issue with this solution is if I have something else in the `<div class="heading-text heading-line">` all the content will goes near the `<h4>`.

Comment: Not according to your code. Limit it to an h4 and not all elements then

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
.heading-text>* {
    position: relative;
}

.short-text {
    display: inline-block;
}

.heading-text h4 {
    font-size: 34px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    letter-spacing: -.7px;
    line-height: 40px;
}

.heading-text.heading-line h4:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 15px;
    bottom: 5px;
    background-color: #fcf8e3;
    z-index: -1
}
```

```html
<div class="heading-text heading-line">
  <h4>
    My super loooong title
  </h4>
</div>

<div class="heading-text heading-line">
  <h4 class="short-text">
    My short title
  </h4>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello, Like the other solution, the issue with this solution is if I have something else in the `<div class="heading-text heading-line">` all the content will goes near the `<h4>`.

Comment: Hi, try adding the .short-text class to h4 itself.. or wherever needed. Hope this helps.